# Is it possible to verify a socket connection is coming from a particular web page?

Tags: websocket

Suppose you implement a streaming api based on websockets at `stream.myapp.com`. One of the consumers of this api is your website `myapp.com`. My question is whether `stream.myapp.com` can verify connections are coming from `myapp.com` webpages loading in the browser. Basically I want to have an authentication layer for non-`myapp.com` connections. Is that possible to do securely? Or will I have to implement something like generating tokens for each page loaded for `myapp.com`?

Comment: The problem here is that a webSocket connection can come from any source and if that source is not a browser, there is no way for you to be able trust anything it tells you.  It could be anything. Usually, the way this problem is solved is the reverse of what you're trying to do.  Create an auth scheme on your web site and use that with your own webSockets from your own web pages.  If that auth is not presented with an incoming webSocket, then somewhat by definition, it must be coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets are not constrained by the same-origin policy, but the protocol defines an Origin header. That's set by the page or server that creates the connection.

This is pretty much how an application that I work on handles this; there's a filter in front of the WebSocket endpoint, which checks the Origin against a list of approved origins (a specific domain, using either HTTP or HTTPS). If this matches, we allow it through; otherwise, it is rejected.

There's a bit more information about using the Origin header in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/115746/81469).

Comment: It doesn't sound like the Origin header works for authentication purposes since you can theoretically change it.

Comment: @ThePuma it's not meant to authenticate the _user_; it's really meant to check that the domain it came from is valid. That appears to be what you're looking for?

Comment: Sort of. It sounds like this method protects against another website connecting to your backend, but it does not protect against an individual who decides to fake the Origin header in their request. To accomplish what I want sounds like it requires some sort of handshake between the website and the streaming backend.